# How is Kendo Grid's DataSourceRequest changing EF statements?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, kendo-ui, kendo-grid

I have a Kendo Grid that reads to the following HttpPost Action in a controller:

```
[HttpPost]
public JsonResult RetrieveBatches([DataSourceRequest] DataSourceRequest request) {
    var original = this._emsRepo.RetrieveDboT_EmsBatches().ToList();
    var changed = this._emsRepo.RetrieveDboT_EmsBatches().ToDataSourceResult(request);
    return this.Json(changed);
}
```

I have a repository class that implements the following:

```
public IEnumerable<DboT_EmsBatches> RetrieveDboT_EmsBatches() {
        return this._con.DboT_EmsBatches.OrderByDescending(x=> x.EmsBatchID);
}
```

where this._con is a Context that contains:

```
public DbSet<DboT_EmsBatches> DboT_EmsBatches { get; set; }
```

with a configuration line in the Context by overriding OnModelCreating():

```
modelBuilder.Configurations.Add(new DboT_EmsBatchesConfiguration());
```

which is a of a simple configuration file that maps to the database table:

```
public DboT_EmsBatchesConfiguration() {
        this.HasKey(t => t.EmsBatchID).ToTable("dbo.T_EmsBatches");
}
```

I don't understand how the ToDataSourceResult(request) will change the IEnumerable or even the select statement the EF sends out?

The original query will execute the sql statement:

```
SELECT 
[Extent1].[EmsBatchID] AS [EmsBatchID], 
[Extent1].[Description] AS [Description], 
[Extent1].[InsertedTimeStamp] AS [InsertedTimeStamp]
FROM [dbo].[T_EmsBatches] AS [Extent1]
ORDER BY [Extent1].[EmsBatchID] DESC
```

which is the proper query that I want.

The changed request will send out a SQL statement of:

```
SELECT 
[Extent1].[EmsBatchID] AS [EmsBatchID], 
[Extent1].[Description] AS [Description], 
[Extent1].[InsertedTimeStamp] AS [InsertedTimeStamp]
FROM ( SELECT [Extent1].[EmsBatchID] AS [EmsBatchID], [Extent1].[Description] AS [Description], [Extent1].[InsertedTimeStamp] AS [InsertedTimeStamp], row_number() OVER (ORDER BY [Extent1].[EmsBatchID] ASC) AS [row_number]
    FROM [dbo].[T_EmsBatches] AS [Extent1]
)  AS [Extent1]
WHERE [Extent1].[row_number] > 0
ORDER BY [Extent1].[EmsBatchID] ASC
```

I am not sure why it's even changing the select statement since my repository is returning an IEnumerable and not an IQueryable?

Answer (score 0):

`DataSourceRequest` object and the `ToDataSourceResult` function are both part of the `Kendo.DynamicLinq` extension for implementing server side paging.

```
using Kendo.DynamicLinq;
```

What `ToDataSourceResult` does is modify your query to collect paging information like total, and takes only the rows needed to be displayed. It then packs that all into a `DataSourceResult` object and passes that to the `Json` function.

[This](http://www.telerik.com/blogs/kendo-ui-open-sources-dynamic-linq-helpers) blog post describes how the extension works.